# INTCK function in SELECT statement SAS

Tags: sas

I am having hard time getting the INTCK function to return the result i am using the following query

```
proc sql;
CREATE TABLE SASAVE.WEEK_NUM AS
SELECT DISTINCT MUC.CODE
        ,MUC.LOB
        ,MMD.MAX_DATE
        ,MMD.MIN_DATE
        ,INTCK('WEEK', MMD.MAX_DATE, MMD.MIN_DATE) AS WEEK_COUNT
FROM    SASAVE.MUC,
        MMD             
WHERE MMD.LOB = MUC.LOB
AND MMD.CODE = MUC.CODE
quit;
```

here is the data in MUC and MMD tables

```
 **MMD**
    MIN_DATE         MAX_DATE       CODE    LOB
    13FEB2012   11MAY2012   527A    TMZ
    13FEB2012   1MAY2012    TB50    ZAE
    13FEB2012   10MAY2012   3O05    ZAA

**MUC**
CODE      LOB
527A    TMZ
TB50    ZAE
3O05    ZAA
```

Can you please let me know if i can get the number of weeks using INTCK function

thanks

Comment: MMD doesn't have MIN_DATE or MAX_DATE

Comment: i have updated the column names.

Comment: This is a reasonable question...I don't understand why it was closed. I am working with OP to solve the problem.

Comment: I don't see any reason to close this either.  Seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Perhaps the people who closed it didn't understand that it was related to SAS software. Is there a way to reopen a question?

Comment: click the reopen option (just below the SAS tag)...we have two already...not sure how many we need

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you had it almost right...this works.

```
Data mmd;
 input min_date:DATE9. max_date:date9. code $ lob $;
 format min_date max_date mmddyy10.;
 datalines;
13FEB2012   11MAY2012   527A    TMZ
13FEB2012   01MAY2012    TB50    ZAE
13FEB2012   10MAY2012   3O05    ZAA
;

Data muc;
 input code $ lob $;
 datalines;
527A    TMZ
TB50    ZAE
3O05    ZAA
;

proc sql;
 CREATE TABLE WEEK_NUM AS
 SELECT DISTINCT MUC.CODE
  ,MUC.LOB
  ,MMD.MAX_DATE
  ,MMD.MIN_DATE
  ,INTCK('WEEK', MMD.MIN_DATE, MMD.MAX_DATE) AS WEEK_COUNT
 FROM MUC, MMD             
 WHERE MMD.LOB = MUC.LOB
  AND MMD.CODE = MUC.CODE;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, but I have few million records in each MMD and MUC table in the SAS database, so how would i do it in that case?

Comment: Why wouldn't the above SQL statement work for your large data sets?

Comment: Actually in the upper case I am entering that datalines values manually in this case it worked out but i can not enter millions of records manually so i am pulling the data from SAS dataset using the below queryproc sql;
 CREATE TABLE WEEK_NUM AS
 SELECT DISTINCT MMD.MED_DEF_CODE
  ,MMD.LINE_OF_BUSINESS AS LOB
  ,MMD.MAX_OF_CLAIM_INSERT_DATE AS MAX_DATE
  ,MMD.MIN_OF_CLAIM_INSERT_DATE AS MIN_DATE
  ,INTCK('WEEK', MMD.MIN_OF_CLAIM_INSERT_DATE, MMD.MAX_OF_CLAIM_INSERT_DATE) AS WEEK_COUNT
 FROM SASAVE.MIN_MAX_DATE MMD quit;

Comment: proc sql;
 CREATE TABLE WEEK_NUM AS
 SELECT DISTINCT MMD.MED_DEF_CODE
  ,MMD.LINE_OF_BUSINESS AS LOB
  ,MMD.MAX_OF_CLAIM_INSERT_DATE AS MAX_DATE
  ,MMD.MIN_OF_CLAIM_INSERT_DATE AS MIN_DATE
  ,INTCK('WEEK', MMD.MIN_OF_CLAIM_INSERT_DATE, MMD.MAX_OF_CLAIM_INSERT_DATE) AS WEEK_COUNT
 FROM SASAVE.MIN_MAX_DATE MMDquit;

Comment: I think you need to restate your question. If you need help getting the input data sets for the PROC SQL that I provided...ask that. I assumed you had two data sets to join by LOB and CODE, in which one had 2 dates you also wanted the # of weeks between. If that is not true...post the question again. I can't address your SQL in the comment if I don't know the input data...if you help me understand, I will help

Comment: S orry about that, I tried your code in my table which has millions of records. I copy and paste my records in datalines from my table but I am not getting any data just the blank table.

Comment: The datalines Data step was just to demonstrate with the sample code. You should be able to use this PROC SQL with your tables. Aren't MMD and MUC SAS data sets? That's what I meant by restating your question. If your data is not already as SAS data set, we can work to get it that way. If your data is already in SAS data sets, why can't you access them from the PROC SQL statement?

Comment: INTCK('WEEK', (datepartMMD.MIN_DATE), datepart(MMD.MAX_DATE)) AS WEEK_COUNT

Comment: you need to move your parenthesis around mmd.min_date. Are min_date and max_date timestamps?